# Comparing two trees to see if they are the same

Tags: algorithm, tree

I have used Neighbor-joining to infer a phylogenetic tree.  I have also done bootstrapping but it is not clear how to compare the topologies of the bootstrap replicates with that of the original tree.  For example, is Node A of the original tree recovered in the Boostrap replicate?  What is the algorithm to compare the topology of two unrooted trees?

Example:

[Two trees that need to be compared to see if some nodes are different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75mwL.png)

[Tree to be compared to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrfsl.png)